# Como selecionar/desselecionar, a cada clique do mouse, um input select multiple? (sem o Ctrl)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou tentando fazer um script para selecionar várias `options` de um `<select multiple>` a cada clique do mouse. Até ai tudo bem, eu consegui e segue o código:

```
var numSelected = 0;
var valSelectedArray = [];

$(document).on('mouseup', '#CentroCusto_new option', function () {
    var valSelected = $(this).val();
    valSelectedArray[numSelected] = valSelected;
    numSelected++;

    for (i = 0; i < numSelected; i++) {
            $("#CentroCusto_new option[value=" + valSelectedArray[i] + "]").prop("selected", true);
    }
});
```

Porém, eu gostaria que ao clicar em um já selecionado ele desselecionasse.

Meu algoritmo está bem ruim e ele dá um efeito de 'piscar' sempre que clico em uma nova `option`, ou seja, ele mostra um apenas selecionado na hora do clique para depois adicionar os outros que já foram clicados anteriormente, isso também não ficou legal.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como incrementar a opção desselecionar no meu código, ou então mostrar um código mais eficiente?

OBS: NÃO QUERO UTILIZAR NENHUM PLUGIN.

Comment: Você não quer o modo de seleção normal com CTRL, é isso?

Comment: Você tem um multipleselect (plugin jQuery) ou está a fazer o seu próprio? dá para adicionar o HTML?

Comment: Sim, não quero que o usuário precise usar o Ctrl. O html não se faz necessário pois ele é simples e com conteúdo dinamico, o id é #CentroCusto_new. Esse post é sobre um plugin, já havia entrado nele, mas quero o meu próprio.

Comment: Vou quebrar a cabeça mais um pouco e caso consiga posto o resultado aqui.

Comment: Seria legal adicionar ao título da pergunta, e deixar bem claro, que é sem o Ctrl, algo como **(sem o Ctrl)**. 

Provavelmente essa pergunta será usada por pessoas no futuro :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente isto:

```
$('select#CentroCusto_new option').on('mousedown', function (event) {
    this.selected = !this.selected;
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Com isso, assim que você apertar o botão do mouse (*mousedown*) em cima do elemento, a opção *selected* recebe o oposto do estado anterior da mesma.

O `event.preventDefault()` faz com que a ação padrão associada a aquele evento não seja acionada/ativada.

Por exemplo, se o evento fosse sobre uma tag 
`<a href="http://testlink.com">`, você não seria direcionado para uma nova Url.

No nosso caso, o `preventDefault` faz com que a ação (padrão) de desmarcar todas as outras entradas quando você clica em um item (sem o Ctrl) não seja executada. Note que desabilitar a ação padrão também faz com que o item não seja selecionado automaticamente, por isso a necessidade do `this.selected = !this.selected;`

Mais informações sobre o *preventDefault* [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Prova de conceito:

http://jsfiddle.net/RkJS7/2/

Comment: Perfeito! Poderia dar uma breve explicação sobre o preventDefault? e o parametro "e" o que é?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Adicionei as explicações que você pediu :)

Answer (score -1):

João Paulo, por padrão um `<select multiple>` pode ter vários elementos selecionados ou desselecionados usando <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd>, e também arrastando o clique do mouse.

Comment: Valeu pela edição @Paulo Roberto, essa do <kbd> eu realmente não sabia

Comment: Disponha, se quiser saber mais: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites e também http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Muito bom, tem várias coisas que eu não sabia que fava pra fazer, gostei mesmo